# Searchable database with Java and SQL

Tags: java, homework, swing, sqlite, jdbc

##### What does the code do?

Albeit unfinished (it does work, it's just not complete yet), the code creates a database (`members.db`) where telephone numbers, IDs, and names are stored. After which, the user can input what they'd like to do, e.g. show every telephone number in the db, every surname etc. The plan further down the line is to implement a backup function as well.

---

The code works as it is now, but I think it could be refactored to shorten it, which is what I'd like.

```java
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class memberList {
    private static File dBfile = new File("members.db");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (!dBfile.exists())
            createNewTable();
        int choice = 0;
        do {
            choice = showMenu();
            if (choice != 0) {
                switch (choice) {
                    case 1:
                        showAllSurname();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        showAllTelephone();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        } while (choice != 0);

    }

    private static int showMenu() {
        String menu = "[1] Show all surnames" + "\n"
                + "[2] Show all telephone numbers";
        return parseInt(showInputDialog(menu + "\n" + "Please choose between 0 - 2:"));
    }

    private static void createNewTable() {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:members.db";
        Connection connect = null;
        Scanner read = null;
        Statement stat = null;

        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            stat = connect.createStatement();
            String str = "CREATE TABLE members (nr integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, fName varchar(25), lName varchar(25), address varchar(35), tlf integer);";
            stat.executeUpdate(str);
            try {
                String line;
                File mlm = new File("register.txt");
                read = new Scanner(mlm);

                while (read.hasNext()) {
                    line = read.nextLine();
                    String[] dB = line.split("[;]");

                    if (dB.length == 6) {
                        int nr = parseInt(dB[0]);
                        String fName = dB[1], lName = dB[2], address = dB[3];
                        int nr1 = parseInt(dB[4]);

                        str = "INSERT INTO members VALUES (" + nr + ",'" + fName + "','" + lName + ",'" + address
                                + ",'" + nr1 + ");";
                        stat.executeUpdate(str);
                    } else {
                        int nr = parseInt(dB[0]);
                        String fName = dB[1], lName = dB[2], address = dB[3];

                        str = "INSERT INTO members VALUES (" + nr + ",'" + fName + "','" + lName + ",'" + address
                                + ",'" + null + ");";
                        stat.executeUpdate(str);
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
                out.println("Not found!");
            } finally {
                if (read != null) {
                    read.close();
                }
            }
            out.println("Connected");
        } catch (SQLException exc) {
            out.println(exc.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (connect != null) {
                    connect.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        showMessageDialog(null, "Start: Creates the table");
    }

    private static void showAllSurname() {

        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:members.db";
        Connection connect = null;
        Statement stat = null;

        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            stat = connect.createStatement();

            String str = "SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY lName";
            ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(str);

            int i = 0, j = i;

            while (res.next()) {
                i++;
            }

            String[][] lNameTab = new String[i][6];

            res = stat.executeQuery(str);

            while (res.next()) {
                String nr = res.getString("nr"), lName = res.getString("lName"), fName = res.getString("fName"),
                        address = res.getString("address"), tlf = res.getString("tlf");
                lNameTab[j - i][0] = nr;
                lNameTab[j - i][1] = lName;
                lNameTab[j - i][2] = fName;
                lNameTab[j - i][3] = address;
                lNameTab[j - i][4] = tlf;
                i--;
            }

            String out = "";
            for (i = 0; i < lNameTab.length; i++) {

                out += lNameTab[i][0] + "|" + lNameTab[i][1] + "|" +
                        lNameTab[i][2] + "|" + lNameTab[i][3] + "|" +
                        lNameTab[i][4] + "|" + lNameTab[i][5] + "|" + "\n";

            }
            showMessageDialog(null, "1: All members, sorted by surname" + "\n" + out);

        } catch (SQLException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (connect != null) {
                    connect.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException exc) {
                System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    private static void showAllTelephone() {

        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:members.db";
        Connection connect = null;
        Statement stat = null;

        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            stat = connect.createStatement();

            String str = "SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY tlf";

            ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(str);

            int i = 0, j = i;

            while (res.next()) {
                i++;
            }

            String[][] tlfTab = new String[i][6];

            res = stat.executeQuery(str);

            while (res.next()) {
                String nr = res.getString("nr"), lName = res.getString("lName"),
                        fName = res.getString("fName"), address = res.getString("address"), tlf = res.getString("tlf");

                tlfTab[j - i][0] = nr;
                tlfTab[j - i][1] = lName;
                tlfTab[j - i][2] = fName;
                tlfTab[j - i][3] = address;
                tlfTab[j - i][4] = tlf;

                i--;
            }

            String out = "";
            for (i = 0; i < tlfTab.length; i++) {

                out += tlfTab[i][0] + "|" + tlfTab[i][1] + "|" +
                        tlfTab[i][2] + "|" + tlfTab[i][3] + "|" +
                        tlfTab[i][4] + "|" + tlfTab[i][5] + "|" + "\n";

            }

            showMessageDialog(null, "2: All members, sorted by telephone" + "\n" + out);

        } catch (SQLException exc) {
            out.println(exc.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (connect != null) {
                    connect.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException exc) {
                out.println(exc.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: (Good thing you not only noticed adverse repetition, but took (meta) action to remedy this.)

Comment: @200_success I've edited the question. Hopefully it's better asked now.

Comment: Since it has a description, I guess it does not deserve downvotes anymore. However @telometto your code does not compile at line 39: `parseInt(showInputDialog(meny + "\n" + "Please choose between 0 - 2:"));` the "meny" variable does not exists (but "menu" with a "u").

Comment: @gervais.b Yes, it's a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. I have fixed it now.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Block form over statement form

> ```
>         if (!dBfile.exists())
>             createNewTable();
> ```

This is a risky pattern.  Say you (or someone else, perhaps a Python developer) want to add logging.  So just add a log statement, right?

```
        if (!dBfile.exists())
            log("No DB File found");
            createNewTable();
```

But wait, does that do what was intended?  Well, no, not in Java (a similar edit would work in Python).  Instead of only creating the file if none exists, it will now always attempt to create a new table.  Whereas if you had

```
        if (!dBfile.exists()) {
            createNewTable();
        }
```

Future edits would naturally do

```
        if (!dBfile.exists()) {
            // can add more statements here
            createNewTable();
            // or here
        }
```

If you feel that you absolutely must use the other form, consider

```
        if (!dBfile.exists()) createNewTable();
```

which is harder to edit badly.  And is even shorter.

If you're concerned about readability, I would point out that the block form is strictly more readable.

#### Pluralize plurals

> ```
>                         showAllSurname();
> ```

This should be

```
                        showAllSurnames();
```

Not terribly important, but pedants like me will notice things like that.

#### Remove redundancy

> ```
>         int choice = 0;
>         do {
>             choice = showMenu();
>             if (choice != 0) {
>                 switch (choice) {
>                     case 1:
>                         showAllSurname();
>                         break;
>                     case 2:
>                         showAllTelephone();
>                         break;
>                     default:
>                         break;
>                 }
>             }
>
>         } while (choice != 0);
> ```

This could be

```
        for (;;) {
            showMenu();
            switch (parseMenuResponse()) {
                case 0:
                    return;
                case 1:
                    showAllSurnames();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    showAllTelephones();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I removed the `default` case, as it had no effect.  You can always add it back later if you want to do something with it.  Note that it is not necessary to put a `break` in the last case.  By convention, I will usually leave it out of the default case if it is last.

There's no need to have an `if` and a `while` checking the same condition.  This form uses the switch to process everything, even a `0` input.

I separated the input fetching and parsing from the display.  As a general rule, it is recommended to either have a side effect (e.g. displaying output) or a return value, not both.  This is a particular case of the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

#### `try`-with-resources

> ```
>             try {
>                 String line;
>                 File mlm = new File("register.txt");
>                 read = new Scanner(mlm);
>
>                 while (read.hasNext()) {
>                     line = read.nextLine();
>                     String[] dB = line.split("[;]");
>
>                     if (dB.length == 6) {
>                         int nr = parseInt(dB[0]);
>                         String fName = dB[1], lName = dB[2], address = dB[3];
>                         int nr1 = parseInt(dB[4]);
>
>                         str = "INSERT INTO members VALUES (" + nr + ",'" + fName + "','" + lName + ",'" + address
>                                 + ",'" + nr1 + ");";
>                         stat.executeUpdate(str);
>                     } else {
>                         int nr = parseInt(dB[0]);
>                         String fName = dB[1], lName = dB[2], address = dB[3];
>
>                         str = "INSERT INTO members VALUES (" + nr + ",'" + fName + "','" + lName + ",'" + address
>                                 + ",'" + null + ");";
>                         stat.executeUpdate(str);
>                     }
>                 }
>             } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
>                 out.println("Not found!");
>             } finally {
>                 if (read != null) {
>                     read.close();
>                 }
>             }
> ```

You could write this more briefly as

```
            try (Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("register.txt"))) {
                while (read.hasNext()) {
                    String[] dB = read.nextLine().split("[;]");

                    int nr = parseInt(dB[0]);
                    String fName = dB[1];
                    String lName = dB[2];
                    String address = dB[3];

                    str = "INSERT INTO members VALUES (" + nr + ", '" + fName + "', '" + lName
                        + ", '" + address + "', ";
                    if (dB.length == 6) {
                        int nr1 = parseInt(dB[4]);
                        str += nr1;
                    } else {
                        str += "NULL";
                    }
                    str += ");"

                    stat.executeUpdate(str);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
                out.println("Not found!");
            }
```

Switching to the [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) form eliminates the need for a `finally` block.

Since you don't handle it other than to produce output, you might drop the `catch` block as well.  I haven't examined your logic in great detail, but this seems like a fatal condition to me.  Rather than catching the exception, it might be better to let it go.  Then if this happens, your program crashes immediately.

As is, you would continue on to attempt more processing.  That processing will probably fail and cause more output.  And it could cause side effects (e.g. modifications to your database).  If you crash instead, you will know exactly where things went south and won't have to filter out additional information.  Catching an exception that you don't handle is a well known anti-pattern.

Try to only initialize one variable per line.  The compiler won't care, but this way is easier to read.

I'm not convinced of the utility of parsing a `String` into an `int` only to convert it back to a `String`.  But it may have useful side effects and it will be easier to switch to parameterized queries later, so I left it.

You don't need redundant code inside your `if`.  If the same code is in both branches of the `if`, then try to factor it out of the `if`.  Then only the different code will be there.  Both shorter and easier to read.

I removed the implicit conversion from `null` to the string `"null"` and replaced it with the explicit string `"NULL"`.  I simply find that to be more reliable and easier to follow.  It also may save you from having a PHP developer convert it to an empty string, as that's the default behavior in PHP.

#### Future things to do

Read up on `Connection.prepareStatement` with parameters.  When doing a query inside a loop, this will be more efficient than rebuilding the entire query every time.

You could break out most of these methods into their own classes.  The new classes could have fewer dependencies per class.  In particular, you might migrate your database calls to Database Access Objects.  This might help reduce some of the boilerplate in your methods.

Comment: Amazing and thorough answer! Thanks a lot for your time and effort!

Answer (score 3):

Well there are indeed some improvements on different subjects:

## Conventions

Java has a naming convention that use *UpperCamlCase* for classes,
*UPPER_HYPHEN_CASE* for static fields. And, when applicable, you should mark
your constant as `final`:

```
public class MemberList {
    private static final DB_FILE = new File("members.db");
```

## Separation of concerns

Your `MemberList` class mix three different concerns/layers:

1. User interface
2. Controls
3. Persistence

This looks very much like the *MVC* pattern who is a common pattern when building
user faced applications. You should try to extract all the 3 roles to different
classes:

### `MemberListPersistence` or `MemberListModel`

There are in fact two classes to extract. In an *MVC* application, the model
keeps the datas, the view "receive" those datas and display them. The controller
receive the actions from the view and update the model.

So you should also, ideally, create an intermediate model between the view and
the persistence. There is also another pattern called *Data Access Object* that
is used to encapsulate the data access. But we can go one step at time and start
to extract the persistence to one dedicated class.

Let's create one `MemberListPersistence` interface so that you can easily test
other layers or change the implementation.

```
interface MemberListPersistence {
    List<String> getAllSurnames();

    List<String> getAllTelephones();
}
```

Quite simple. However, string is not a good type in your case. Because it is too
vague, cannot contain many values (or you have to parse them). So let's create
one anemic model for the return type:

```
class Member {
    final String nr;
    final String lastName;
    final String firstName;
    final String address;
    final String phoneNumber;

    // Constructor
}

interface MemberListPersistence {
    List<Member> getAllSurnames();  

    List<Member> getAllTelephones();
}
```

### `MemberListUi` or `MemberListView`

This is a quite simple class in your case. His role will be to display the menu
and ask for the choice (but not handle it) and print the list of members.

```
interface MemberListView {
    int showMenuAndAsk();

    void print(String title, List<Member> members);
}
```

### MemberListControl

Another simple class that drive the two other. It will delegate to the view to
show the menu and ask for user choice. Then it will call the persistence
according to the user choice and delegate again to the view.

This class may require the `MemberListPersistence` and `MemberListView` in his
constructor. So that it is much easier to test it and switch the implementations.

You can create another class for that or mix it into your "main" class.

```
private final MemberListPersistence persistence;
private final MemberListView view;

public MemberList(MemberListPersistence persistence, MemberListView view) {
    this.persistence = persistence;
    this.view = view;

    int choice;
    do {
        choice = view.showMenuAndAsk();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                showAllSurname();
                break;
            case 2:
                showAllTelephone();
                break;
            default:
        }
    } while (choice!=0);
}


private void showAllSurname() {
    view.print("All members sorted by surname", persistence.getAllBySurnames());
}

private void showAllTelephone() {
    view.print("All members sorted by telephone", persistence.getAllByTelephones());
}

// Usage :

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new MemberList(
        new SqlLiteMemberListPersistence(),
        new DialogsMemberListView()
    );
}
```

## Much more

There are much more to say but at this stage you should have a better structured
application where you can test all components independently. It is not a true MVC
model but still better to evolve.

You can now find the duplications, there are many duplicated lines on your
persistence layer that can be regrouped in one method that only changes the order
by which you want to sort the members.