# Code cleanup for a Java project that creates a database containing members of a club

Tags: java, sqlite

This question is related to my [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71753512/how-can-i-create-a-database-from-a-file-using-java) on this forum. Since the rules are not to make the questions too broad, I thought I'd create a new question.

I'm not experiencing any issues with this piece of code - it seems to work as intended - but is there a way to make this less... "spaghetti"? I'd like to refactor it to make it cleaner, and/or optimize it. PS: I'm new to programming, which is why this probably looks like a gas-station toilet.

---

Method to show all the telephone numbers of the members:

```java
public static void showAllNumbers() {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:members.db";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "select * from Member order by Telephone";

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        int i = 0;

        while (rs.next())
            i++;
        int j = i;

        String[][] telTab = new String[i][6];

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String no = rs.getString("No");
            String lName = rs.getString("First");
            String fName = rs.getString("Last");
            String address = rs.getString("Address");
            String tel = rs.getString("Telephone");

            telTab[j - i][0] = no;
            telTab[j - i][1] = lName;
            telTab[j - i][2] = fName;
            telTab[j - i][3] = address;
            telTab[j - i][4] = tel;

            i--;
        }

        String show = "";
        for (i = 0; i < telTab.length; i++) {

            show += telTab[i][0] + "|" + telTab[i][1] + "|" +
                    telTab[i][2] + "|" + telTab[i][3] + "|" +
                    telTab[i][4] + "|" + "\n";

        }

        showMessageDialog(null, "All members, sorted by telephone number" + "\n" + show);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

---

Method to register new members:

```java
  private static void registerMember() {

    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:members.db";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {

      String fName = showInputDialog(null, "1: First:");
      String lName = showInputDialog(null, "2: Last:");
      String address = showInputDialog(null, "3: Address:");
      int tel = parseInt(showInputDialog("Telephone", 0));

      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

      if (tel == 0) {

        String sql = "insert into Member (First,Last,Address,Telephone) values ('" + fName + "','" + lName
            + "','" +
            address + " '," + null + ");";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

      } else {

        String sql = "insert into Member (First,Last,Address,Telephone) values ('" + fName + "','" + lName
            + "','" +
            address + "'," + tel + ");";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
      try {
        if (conn != null) {
          conn.close();
        }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      }
    }

    showMessageDialog(null, "3: Registered new member");

    out.println("Registered new member");
  }
```

---

Method to execute a backup of the db:

```java
  private static void execBak() {

    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:member.db";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {

      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

      String sql = "create table if not exists MemberBak (no integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, First varchar(50), Last varchar(50), Address varchar(50),by varchar(50),Telephone integer);";
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

      sql = "INSERT or REPLACE INTO MemberBak SELECT * FROM Member;";
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

      System.out.println("Connected!");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
      try {
        if (conn != null) {
          conn.close();
        }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      }

    }

  }
```

---

Method to restore a backup:

```java
  private static void getBak() {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:member.db";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

      String sql = "select * from MemberBak order by Last";

      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      int i = 0;

      while (rs.next())
        i++;
      int j = i;

      String[][] lNameTab = new String[i][6];

      rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      while (rs.next()) {

        String no = rs.getString("no");
        String lName = rs.getString("Last");
        String fName = rs.getString("First");
        String address = rs.getString("Address");
        String tel = rs.getString("Telephone");

        lNameTab[j - i][0] = no;
        lNameTab[j - i][1] = lName;
        lNameTab[j - i][2] = fName;
        lNameTab[j - i][3] = address;
        lNameTab[j - i][4] = tel;

        i--;
      }

      String show = "";
      for (i = 0; i < lNameTab.length; i++) {

        show += lNameTab[i][0] + "|" + lNameTab[i][1] + "|" +
            lNameTab[i][2] + "|" + lNameTab[i][3] + "|" +
            lNameTab[i][4] + "|" + "\n";

      }

      showMessageDialog(null, "Backup complete!" + "\n" + show);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
      try {
        if (conn != null) {
          conn.close();
        }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      }
    }

  }

}
```

There are no errors in the code afaik. I'd just like to make it easier to read, less redundant, and learn how to do so for future projects from people who have this kind of experience.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: This code shows a lot of resemblance with [another recent post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/275375/9357). Are you doing the same homework assignment or something?

Comment: @200_success So it would seem. Apparently, the other one hasn't gotten very far, though.

Comment: Have you read the official [backup documentation](https://sqlite.org/backup.html) ? This method seems ad-hoc and incomplete when compared to theirs.

Comment: Since you agree that your question is very similar to the other one pointed by @200_success why don't you start to read and apply the answers on that similar code ?

Answer (score 1):

It is best to hold your credentials at one spot, so:

```
private static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:members.db";
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
}
```

Then you used an array of array of String to hold the records.
For a single table record I made a class. Java introduced a new class, called `record` for a simple read-only list of fields. I created such a `Member` class.

And as the use of a fixed sized array is awkward, I used the dynamic `List`.
There are several implementation of this interface, like `LinkedList`, but `ArrayList` is most like an array.

Multiline strings """...""" are also relative new in java, embedding newlines and indenting properly.

```
private record Member(long no, String first, String last, String address, int telephone) {
    public String infoString() {
        return "" + no + "|" + first + "|" + last + "|" + address + "|" + telephone + "|";
    }
}
```

The last improvement is to use **try-with-resources**, a bit weird syntax, but the objects declared inside `try (...)` must be `AutoCloseable`, and are automatically closed on the end of the block, whether exception was raised, breaked or returned.

You'll see that also statements and result sets should be closed.

And then there is PreparedStatement, where the SQL contains `?` placeholders to be filled in. This allows type-safe parameters, automatically escapes strings (try typing an apostrophe `'` in your input dialog). And is a security measure against SQL injection.

If you do not want to be bothered with the checked SQLException, you can rethrow it as a RuntimeException, here IllegalStateException. That is far better than writing to the console.

A telephone in an `int` cannot hold 10 digits 9 999 999 999, so reconsider.

```
public static void showAllNumbers() {
    final String sql = "select * from Member order by Telephone";
    try (Connection conn = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {

        List<Member> telTab = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Member member = new Member(rs.getLong("No"),
                rs.getString("First"),
                rs.getString("Last"),
                rs.getString("Address"),
                rs.getInt("Telephone"));
            telTab.add(0, member);
        }

        StringBuilder show = new StringBuilder();
        show.append("All members, sorted by telephone number" + "\n")
        for (Member member: telTab) {
            show.append(member.infoString()).append("\n");
        }

        showMessageDialog(null, show.toString());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}

private static void registerMember() {
    String fName = showInputDialog(null, "1: First:");
    String lName = showInputDialog(null, "2: Last:");
    String address = showInputDialog(null, "3: Address:");
    int tel = parseInt(showInputDialog("Telephone", 0));

    final String sqlWithTel = "insert into Member (First, Last, Address, Telephone) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    final String sqlWithoutTel = "insert into Member (First, Last, Address, Telephone) values (?, ?, ?, null)";
    try (Connection conn = getConnection();
             PreparedStatement stmtWithTel = conn.prepareStatement(sqlWithTel);
             PreparedStatement stmtWithoutTel = conn.prepareStatement(sqlWithoutTel)) {

        if (tel == 0) {
            stmtWithoutTel.setString(1, fName);
            stmtWithoutTel.setString(2, lName);
            stmtWithoutTel.setString(3, address);
            stmtWithoutTel.executeUpdate();
        } else {
            stmtWithTel.setString(1, fName);
            stmtWithTel.setString(2, lName);
            stmtWithTel.setString(3, address);
            stmtWithTel.setInt(4, tel);
            stmtWithTel.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    showMessageDialog(null, "3: Registered new member");
}

private static void execBak() {
    final String sqlCreate = """
        create table if not exists MemberBak (
            no integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
            First varchar(50),
            Last varchar(50),
            Address varchar(50),
            byUser varchar(50),
            Telephone integer)"""; // "by" is an SQL keyword.
    final String sqlInsRepl = "INSERT or REPLACE INTO MemberBak SELECT * FROM Member;";
    try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlCreate)) {
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInsRepl)) {
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        System.out.println("Connected!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}

private static void getBak() {
    final String sql = "select * from MemberBak order by Last";
    try (Connection conn = getConnection();
         PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        
        List<Member> lNameTab = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Member member = new Member(rs.getLong("No"),
                    rs.getString("First"),
                    rs.getString("Last"),
                    rs.getString("Address"),
                    rs.getString("Telephone"));
            lNameTab.add(0, member);
        }

        StringBuilder show = new StringBuilder();
        show.append("Backup complete!" + "\n");
        for (Member member: lNameTab) {
            show.append(member.infoString()).append("\n");
        }

        showMessageDialog(null, show.toString());

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

Evidently you are still not that advanced a developer, so that already suffices.
Your question to reduce the code, remove redundancies is done only to some degree,
like with try-with-resources removing the incomplete closing.